# User defined generic types and collections.abc

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, type-hinting

I have a Python package that defines a variety of collections based on the ABCs provided by *collections.abc* (*Mapping*, *Sequence*, etc). I want to take advantage of the type hinting facilities introduced in Python 3.5, but I'm having doubts as to what would be the best way to go about it.

Lets take one of these classes as an example; until now, I had something
resembling this:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping

class MyMapping(Mapping):
    ...
```

To turn this into a generic type, the [documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#arbitrary-generic-types-as-base-classes) suggests doing something like this:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Hashable, Mapping

K = TypeVar("K", bound=Hashable)
V = TypeVar("V")

class MyMapping(Mapping[K, V]):
    ...
```

But this poses two problems:

- The class looses all the mixin methods from *collections.abc.Mapping*. I could deal with this implementing them myself, but that would defeat part of the purpose of using ABCs in the first place.
- `isinstance(MyMapping(), collections.abc.Mapping)` returns False. Also, trying to call `collections.abc.Mapping.register(MyMapping)` to work around this raises a *RuntimeError* ("Refusing to create an inheritance cycle").

My first attempt to solve these problems was to go back to extending *collections.abc.Mapping*:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Hashable
from collections.abc import Mapping

K = TypeVar("K", bound=Hashable)
V = TypeVar("V")

class MyMapping(Mapping[K, V]):
    ...
```

But that doesn't work, as *collections.abc.Mapping* is not a generic type and does not support the subscription operator. So I tried this:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Hashable, Mapping
from collections.abc import Mapping as MappingABC

K = TypeVar("K", bound=Hashable)
V = TypeVar("V")

class MyMapping(MappingABC, Mapping[K, V]):
    ...
```

But this smells fishy. The imports and aliasing are cumbersome, the resulting class has a tortuous MRO, and the mix-in methods provided by the ABC won't have typing information...

So what is the preferred way to declare a custom generic type based on a collection ABC?

Answer (score 0):

[ Personal Opinion™ ]: I don't really support creating new `typing` features. These should be generic enough to not require any modification on your code. If your mapping class is so sophisticated it cannot be replaced by any common mapping (like `dict`), you are better off just using itself:

```
def foo(bar: MyMapping) -> List:
    pass
```

instead of

```
def foo(bar: Mapping[K, V]) -> List:
    pass
```

Now, if you want your users to be able to "type" check your class with `typing.Mapping`, you just need to subclass `collections.Mapping`

```
class MyMapping(collections.abc.Mapping):
    ... # define required methods

isinstance(MyMapping(), typing.Mapping[K, V]) # --> True
```

Comment: [ My Personal Opinion ]: I'm not big on static typing or type hinting myself, but I understand the allure for some people and the benefits it can provide to IDEs and other tools. I like that it is an optional layer that API writers and users can opt in to.

Comment: I would like users of my API to be able to indicate that one of their functions returns an object of type `MyMapping[str, int]`, if they so choose. If they only want to state it returns MyMapping, or Mapping[str, int], or Mapping... those are all fine too. And if they want to skip type hinting altogether, more power to them. It should be their choice. As it stands, I can say "this function returns an instance of MyMapping" or "this function returns a mapping with string keys and integer values", but I can't mix the two statements. That seems a strange limitation.

Comment: @MartiCongost My point is: your users shouldn't be using your class for static typing... If your class is a mapping, they should be using just `typing.Mapping[K, V]`... Otherwise, they wouldn't be able to pass a `dict` to said function

Comment: I agree that using more generic types on function arguments makes much more sense than constraining your users to a specific choice. But there are other use cases, such as attributes and function return values, where specifying the precise type you are dealing with is advantageous.

Comment: (Just like the docs for the typing module suggest using _Mapping_ or _Sequence_ for function arguments, and to only use _Dict_ and _List_ to indicate return values).

Answer (score 0):

Your original code works fine with the current version of python and mypy, and does everything exactly as you want (including reusing implementation from `collections.abc.Mapping`).

However, for the time being, you should remove the `bound=Hashable`, since it's [not fully supported yet](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/679):

```
from typing import TypeVar, Hashable, Mapping

K = TypeVar("K")
V = TypeVar("V")

class MyMapping(Mapping[K, V]):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. It's been a while and I'm not working on this presently, but I'll give it a try when I can and see if I can accept your answer.